# How do I implement a method that returns an inorder sorted array in a java binary search tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, inorder

This is what I tried:

```
public int[] sortedArray() {
    int[] array = new int[size()];
    int index = 0;
    traverseInorder(root, array, index);
    return array;
}

private void traverseInorder(Node n, int[] array, int index) {
    if (n != null) {
        traverseInorder(n.left, array, index);
        array[index++] = n.value;
        traverseInorder(n.right, array, index);
    }
}
```

But the output is not correct.

If I create a tree with this input:

```
{1,5,8,10,12,15,20,22,25,36,30,40,28,38,48,45,50}
```

The output I get with `sortedArray` is this:

```
[1, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 22, 25, 36, 40, 48, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What did I do wrong? I realize that it skips all the left subtrees on the right side from the root, but I just can't see why...

Comment: Are you sure that your tree is correct?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Primitive types are passed by value. So when you call `traverseInorder` it doesn't update `index` variable.

Comment: Each recursive call to `traverseInorder` needs to communicate an updated `index` value back to its caller.  And because changes to `int` arguments (such as `index`) can't be communicated back through the argument list, the only alternative is for `traverseInorder` to _returrn_ the updated `index` value.

Comment: @KevinAnderson thank you so much for actually being helpful! I implemented you suggestion and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting all the left sub-trees elements written to the array.

Assuming you added the nodes to the tree in the specified order, you'll get the following (extremely unbalanced) tree:

```
   1
    \
     5
      \
       8
        \
         10
          \
           12
            \
             15
               \
                20
                 \
                  22
                   \
                    25
                     \
                     36
                    /  \
                   30   40
                  /    /  \
                 28   38   48
                          /  \
                         45   50
```

You can see that the 4 elements missing from the in-order output (28, 30, 38 & 45) all belong to left sub-trees.

The reason for that behavior is that after `traverseInorder(n.left, array, index);` writes the left sub-tree to the array and returns, any changes that it made to `index` are local, so `array[index++] = n.value;` and `traverseInorder(n.right, array, index)` overwrite the values of the left sub-tree previously written to the array.

To fix this, your recursive method should return the updated index:

```
private int traverseInorder(Node n, int[] array, int index) {
    if (n != null) {
        index = traverseInorder(n.left, array, index);
        array[index++] = n.value;
        index = traverseInorder(n.right, array, index);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **"traverseInorder"** function to the one given below. Hopefully this recursion should work.

```
 private int traverseInorder(Node n, int[] array, int index)
 {
 if(n.left != null)
 index =  traverseInorder(n.left, array, index);

 array[index++] = n.value;

 if(n.right != null)
 index =  traverseInorder(n.right, array, index);

   return index;
}
```

Comment: Did not see the above response as I was posting the answer, but yes both the approaches should work fine, key being proper update of the index value in the recursion.